# Sorting HTML snippets in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I have a need to save some html snippets to an array. These snippets would have something like a position attribute, which I would pass as well.
I want PHP to output all of my snippets in descending order.

I know how to do it in JS/jQuery, by setting my position in a data attribute and then sorting, but I'm unsure how to proceed in PHP.

Any clue to point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you give a slice of array that would have the html snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your elements look like this:

```
array(
    'snippet' => '...html...',
    'position' => 0..n
);
```

and many of them are in another `array()` without any particular indexes. Then you could do:

```
$array = ...; // as described above
usort(
    &$array,
    function ($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a['position'] == $b['position'])
            return 0;
        return ($a['position'] < $b['position'] ? -1 : 1);
    }
);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Thanks! What if my html snippets contain php variables too? I guess I have to first compose my array then do the sorting

Comment: I found this method too on w3schools

    $age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");
    ksort($age);

which sounds a lot easier. What is the difference with your solution?

Comment: @Akmur This array is being sorted by keys and the keys contains names.

Comment: when you say "this" what "this" are you referring to? :) sorry not sure what you mean

Comment: @Akmur This being the array you posted in your comment there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you could populate the array in many place, and in no particular order.

```
$htmlSnippets = new Array();
$htmlSnippets[1] = "<secondsnippet>";
$htmlSnippets[0] = "<firstsnippet>";
$htmlSnippets[2] = "<thirdsnippet>";

ksort($htmlSnippets);
foreach( $htmlSnippets as $snippet ){
    echo $snippet;
}
```